# Youth Safehouse

Tags: society, law, safety, daily-life

Youth in their teens come to this safehouse from hundreds of miles away in order to find safety from their family, develop a sense of personal identity, and have a place to stay while they build a life of there own. The safehouse is run by a single, older lady, who provides them with shelter and basic necessities. The building itself has roughly a dozen bedrooms, though up to 50 youth may live here at any given time.

The existence of this safehouse passed around by word of mouth, recommend by former residents to those in unsafe environments. Residents come to escape family, poverty, abuse, and the like. The owner asks no questions, only takes care of them as needed.

The safehouse is not legally sanctioned, for a few reasons:

1. Occupancy often exceeds the legal limit, with residents sharing beds or even sleeping on the floor (with blankets and pillows, of course)
2. Many residents are minors who are sheltering without the knowledge of their parents, which could constitute kidnapping.
3. The owner keeps no record of residents, allowing for people to potentially slip through the cracks without a trace.
4. The owner does not have social work license expected for this work.
5. The number of residents far exceeds the number of caretakers (1).

Though residents are not restricted on the duration of their stay, most of them usually leave after a short (week-month) stay. They may return to their families if they determine it's safe to do so, sort out personal matters, or save up from work before starting a life on their own.

Residents come from a variety of backgrounds. They may seek refuge from abuse at home. Others may be looking for freedom of lifestyle. Assault victims and LGBT youth are the main demographic, however, race, class, and other factors are mostly mixed together.

Keeping that many youth under one room can pose challenges in terms of visibility. A few to think of:

1. Residents come and go as they please. A curfew prevents late night wanderings, but during the day food, work, and play are all reasons to wander about the city.
2. Not everyone gets along. Fights, heated arguments, and the like can break out, drawing attention to the safehouse.
3. Sickness and accidents happen. A trip to the hospital is inevitable, and a minor without parents is a serious matter to hospital workers.
4. The owner will regularly need to purchase bulk quantities of necessities.
5. The owner has a life of her own, and those close to her will also know about the safe house.
6. All in addition to the loose ends of having so many people keep a secret.

**How can the safehouse stay under the radar from authorities who might shut down this safehouse for legal reasons, as well as from disgruntled family members seeking to reclaim their child?**

Comment: This depends *enormously* on what country this youth shelther operates in. There are many countries where fifty young vagabonds living under one roof would be completely unremarkable. There are many countries where the very notion of a "social work license" does not even exist in practical life. (Not to mention that until about one hundred years ago the authorities wouldn't have bothered at all with this shelter anywhere on Earth.)

Comment: How is this a question of worldbuilding?

Comment: This sounds like a perfect recruiting trap for human traffickers.

Comment: Is there no CPS? Is there a reason teenagers operate like escaped slaves on the underground railroad?

Comment: If this operates in a less developed country, then it would be perfectly acceptable. Minors are regularly placed into conditions far worse than this there and she would be viewed as a hero by some. In a developed country, all it takes is an injury/illness requiring hospitalization and the woman would go to jail. If you really want to make this realistic, place this in a poor country. Another problem could be that a human trafficker could pretend to be a teenager and kidnap the children.